Applying data analytics to a discrete model railway simulation
I have developed a discrete model that successfully simulates a railway system, emulating a 1 hour train ride between 12 stops. I am now looking to enhance this model by incorporating data which will allow users to view emissions generation for three different train types: diesel, electric, and hybrid.(I have this data in excel ready to upload)
My goal is to have the user interface initially display six options representing the six train models included in the data. Once a model is selected, the simulation should run with the corresponding data presented alongside it.
I am comfortable incorporating this data into the model using the table function. However, I am unsure how to extrapolate the data and create graphics or analysis to run alongside the simulation. Could you please suggest ways to achieve this?
I can upload the data via the table function however I do not understand how to associate the data with my model. Additionally, if integrating the data directly with the model is not feasible, I would appreciate advice on how to implement the data as graphs.
data I want to implement
simulation currently running with no data
